# AlamofireImage : Cache empty after each app launch

Tags: image, alamofire, alamofireimage

I'm using AlamofireImage to download images and cache it continously in the app.

The problem is that after each launch of the app the cache is empty.

Why is this problem happening? I want to keep the cache along the different sessions and not to download the images again and again in each session.

Is someone having the same problem than me?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the documentation of Alamofire Image, it seems that is uses an [in-memory cache](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AlamofireImage/3.2.0/Classes/AutoPurgingImageCache.html) rather than a storage cache. Most probably the cache is purged when the app is closed to reduce memory usage.
For more information, see the [Image Cache part of the documentation](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AlamofireImage/3.2.0/index.html).

If you want to make sure the cached images are still available after reloading your app, you should use a library that stores the cached images in storage rather than in memory.

Comment: Correct, AFI relies on `URLCache` for disk caching.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation.